# When setting a class property inside a method, does it need to be released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I'm very new to Objective-C.  I kept on getting a runtime error when trying to set a class variable inside a method and then releasing it.  I realized the only way to get rid of the runtime error is not to release it.
So if a class variable is set inside a method, the temp method variable doesn't need to be released?

My code looked something like this:

```
- (void)initData{
      NSMutableArray *tmpData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      self.data = tmpData;

      [tmpData release];
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the declaration of data?

Comment: @iccir is right—we need more code. Releasing `tmpData` is releasing from memory the object to which both `tmpData` and `self.data` are pointing.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "class property" or "class variable". Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *data;

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is correct if the `data` property is declared with a "retain" or "copy" attribute. If `data` is declared with an "assign" attribute (the default), what you've got will cause a crash. The solution in that case is to use retain (or possibly copy) for `data`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
```

Comment: Or `strong`, which is a synonym for `retain` under MRC and the replacement for `retain` under ARC.

Comment: Also, worth clarifying: Under MRC, `initData` *must* send `[tmpData release]`, *regardless of the declaration of the property*, because it owns the object (because it created it with `alloc`) and is about to return. If it does not release `tmpData`, it will leak it. If the property is declared as `strong`/`retain` or `copy` and the release still causes a crash, then a bug lay elsewhere and the questioner must hunt it down in Instruments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My property setting is as follows:  @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *data;  So now my understanding is that "assign" does not increment the reference count when I assign an object to this variable, whereas "retain" would increment the reference count and I'd be able to release the local method variable with no problems?

Comment: @LeoL: Correct, and since you must release the object via the local variable anyway (to clean up the local ownership), it is the property (which lacks an instance-level ownership) that is wrong. Don't think about whether you can get away with releasing something or not; think about ownerships, and keeping every ownership's establishment and release balanced.